# Incremental Encoder problem

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor, signal, plc

I have a problem is that it is not possible to specify the direction of rotation in the encoder. Refer to it as in the attached picture.enter image description here.

[image]

The problem with the selection is that at the start of the encoder operation, I cannot determine the correct direction of rotation, because both signals A and B do not overlap.

Comment: Have you looked into any standard encoder library how it’s implemented.

Comment: Link to the encoder, please. You are right that at the start you would have a very difficult time deciding the direction. I'd like to see the entire datasheet.

Comment: are you certain that your waveforms are correct? ... you can buy an encoder that repeatedly clicks signal A when turned in one direction and repeatedly clicks signal B when turned in the other direction

Answer (score 4):

The encoder signal pair on your picture looks ill. You are completely right, that you can't determine the direction not at start, nor any other time because of both signals do not overlap.
In fact, in this case, the second signal gives a very little information in addition to the first one.

Is it a real encoder?
The right signal must be overlapping like this
[image]